# Accessing managed object in a c# callback passed to a native dll

Tags: c#, delphi, pinvoke

I'm trying to pass a C# callback function to a native dll. It works fine, but I couldn't find a way to access the parent object of the callback method. Here's a code which demonstrates what I want to do:

```
class MyForm: Form {
  public delegate void CallbackDelegate(IntPtr thisPtr);

  [DllImport("mylib.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
  public static extern void Test(CallbackDelegate callback);

  int Field;

  static void Callback(IntPtr thisPtr)
  {
      // I need to reference class field Field here.
      MyForm thisObject = ?MagicMethod?(thisPtr);

      thisObject.Field = 10;
  }

  void CallExternalMethod()
  {
      Test(Callback);
  }
}
```

I tried getting the pointer of `this` but I got the following exception: "Object contains non-primitive or non-blittable data.". I should probably mention that the parent object is a WindowsForms form.

**UPDATE**

The dll is written in Delphi and the signature of the Test function is the following:

```
type
  TCallback = procedure of object; stdcall;

procedure Test(Callback: TCallback); stdcall;
```

I received the above error message when I tried to get the pointer to the class with the following code:

```
var ptr = GCHandle.Alloc(this, GCHandleType.Pinned).AddrOfPinnedObject();
```

Comment: How's your native Test method in mylib.dll declared? I'm not asking for the definition, just the signature of the method.

Comment: Can you give more code.

Comment: @David Heffernan I'm actually making up the code, rather than copying the original to avoid irrelevant details. I think I wrote all the relevant code. What is missing?

Comment: I have some experience of p/invoke interop to Delphi. And callbacks. But I have simply no idea what you are trying to do. I would love to see a complete program that demonstrates the error.

Comment: The p/invoke part works perfectly fine. I don't know how to reference fields of MyForm instance from the static callback method. The exception is raised when I try to get the pointer to MyForm instance with `GCHandle.Alloc(this, GCHandleType.Pinned)`. But I'm not sure if that is a correct way for doing what I want. I have updated the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are over thinking this. The C# marshalling will create a thunk around your delegate. You must not attempt to do so.

On the Delphi side write it like this:

```
type
  TCallback = procedure; stdcall;
```

Simply remove the `of object`.

On the C# side your delegate is:

```
public delegate void CallbackDelegate();
```

The method that you use for your delegate looks like this:

```
void Callback()
{
    // an instance method, so *this* is available
}
```

And then you call into the native code like this:

```
void CallExternalMethod()
{
    Test(Callback);
}
```

So, let's put it all together. On the Delphi side you can write:

```
library MyLib;

type
  TCallback = procedure; stdcall;

procedure Test(Callback: TCallback); stdcall;
begin
  Callback;
end;

exports
  Test;

begin
end.
```

And on the C# side:

```
class MyForm: Form {
    public delegate void CallbackDelegate();

    [DllImport("mylib.dll")]
    public static extern void Test(CallbackDelegate callback);

    int Field;

    static void Callback()
    {
        Field = 10;
    }

    void CallExternalMethod()
    {
        Field = 0;
        Test(Callback);
        Debug.Assert(Field == 10);
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow! This is really bizarre. So thisPtr is like a dummy parameter here. Thank you very much! That indeed works.

Comment: You need to remove the thisPtr on both sides. Let the marshaller thunk it for you.

Comment: Here's another question on the topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15666173/how-do-non-static-callbacks-work-from-native-code

Comment: One thing I forgot to mention is that I cannot remove `of object` from delphi declarion, because it is being used in other parts too. But your before-edit solution worked fine.

Comment: Well, that's a problem. The C# delegate is a single pointer type. The Delphi `of object` pointer is a two pointer type. You really ought to write an adapter layer. You may make it work by good fortune with an extra pointer parameter on the C# side which you ignore, that corresponds to the Delphi `Self` implicit parameter. But that would be pretty wacky. The C# thunk is going to give you the managed `this` no matter what.

Comment: That's what confused me at first. I knew that `of object` passed `Self` as the first argument, but I didn't know that C# wrapped the non-static delegate into a thunk.

Answer (score 0):

You're supposed to use the `System.Runtime.InteropServices.GCHandle` class, [its MSDN documentation has examples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.gchandle.fromintptr.aspx?cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2). It involves using its static methods to convert from C# reference to and from an unmanaged value.

I have no quick way to check, but something like this should work:

```
static void Callback(IntPtr thisPtr)
{
    MyForm thisObject = (MyForm)GCHandle.FromIntPtr(thisPtr).Target;

    thisObject.Field = 10;
}
```

The `IntPtr` should be obtained like this:

```
IntPtr thisPtr = GCHandle.ToIntPtr(GCHandle.Alloc(thisObject)));
```

**PS:** Note that at some point you have to free the handle, either in the callee or in the caller.

Comment: I have updated my question. Could you provide the code to do this? I was trying to use this class, but was unsuccessful.

Comment: @Max I have no quick way to test if this works, but it's the general idea.

Comment: That is what I was doing, except that I used `GCHandleType.Pinned` parameter. I thought that you are not allowed to pass unpinned pointers to native code.

Comment: Your main problem was using `AddrOfPinnedObject` instead of `ToIntPtr`. A `GCHandle` is not a raw pointer, it's more of a cookie to reconstruct the managed pointer (and maintain an "artificial" reference on the object so it's not GC'd).